# UFT API authentication

Tags: authentication

I need help with setting up Authentication for soap webservice, I'm using UFT 12.02, I've tried following steps >>Properties / Event / BeforeApplyProtocolSettings / New Handler then typed below code:

public void StServiceCallActivity4_OnBeforeApplyProtocolSettings(object sender, HP.ST.Ext.WebServicesActivities.Models.StChannelsBindingStack args)
        {
            //string myAuth = "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
            this.StServiceCallActivity4.HttpRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization","Basic QUNOOmllMkM1RzZiczgNCg==");

```
    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong,I'm getting "401 : Unauthorized".(I used same user name and password in SOAPUI and it worked fine.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong,
In the snippet "
string myAuth = "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
"
I added space after Basic word("Basic ") and it worked fine.Full code is`string myAuth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")); this.StServiceCallActivity4.HttpRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",myAuth);`